# Read a jsp page content to html in other jsp page

Tags: java, html, jsp

I have two JSP files: `a.jsp` and `b.jsp`.

1. `a.jsp` reads data from a database and display it (already done).
2. `b.jsp` should read `a.jsp` as an HTML page and write it as a string `s`.

How should I write the function to read the result of `a.jsp` and write it as a string?

Comment: Are you asking how to pass your data set to another JSP?

Comment: Please post the code you have tried.

Comment: I want to read a.jsp to a string of html code to custom this string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use JSTL, then you can use the import tag. Here is example code.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%> 
<c:import url="a.jsp" var="aString"/>
This is the import of a.jsp ---- ${aString}
Or if you want to do scripting ---- <%=pageContext.getAttribute("aString")%>
```

If you don't use JSTL, then you can use something like the following.

```
<%@ page import="java.net.*,java.io.*" %>
<%
URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/a.jsp");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
if(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK == conn.getResponseCode()){
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()), 8192);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = "";
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
    }
    in.close(); 
    out.print("import of a.jsp is ----" + sb.toString());
}else out.print("Response code is " + conn.getResponseCode());
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

in `b.jsp` you can use **jsp include tag**

```
<jsp:include page="a.jsp" />
```